# Configuring static analysis or linters for C++ with Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel, clang-format, clang-static-analyzer

I'm teaching myself C++ and working on a small project with Bazel. I'd like to make sure I'm writing safe code and following reasonable best practices, but I'm not sure how to go about doing so. I'm aware of several static analysis tools such as [tsan](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) and other [analyzers](https://github.com/google/sanitizers), [clang-tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/), or [cpplint](https://github.com/google/styleguide/tree/gh-pages/cpplint).

However I'm not sure how I'm supposed to go about setting these tools up with Bazel. Some poking around has found custom-looking solutions such as [Drake](https://drake.mit.edu/code_style_tools.html) (see [`cpplint.bzl`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tools/lint/cpplint.bzl)) or [apollo](https://github.com/ApolloAuto/apollo/blob/master/tools/cpplint.bzl), but it seems weird to need to write a bunch of custom build toolchain logic in order to make these work. Is there a proper way to set these up?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a great answer yet, and I'm still surprised it's this manual, but I have at least got `cpplint.py` and `clang-tidy` working, like so:

### cpplint

I added this target to my `src/BUILD` file (you'll want to configure `--filter` as needed):

```
py_test(
    name = "cpplint",
    srcs = ["@google_styleguide//:cpplint/cpplint.py"],
    data = [":all_cpp_files"],
    # Not sure if there's a better way to express the paths to the src/ dir
    # Drake uses the location oparator, but needs to jump through hoops to get the list of targets
    args = ["--root=src", "--linelength=100", "--counting=detailed",
            "--filter=..."] +
        ["src/%s" % f for f in glob(["**/*.cc", "**/*.h"])],
    main = "cpplint.py",
    python_version = "PY2",
)
```

The `@google_styleguide` workspace is defined like so:

```
new_git_repository(
    name = "google_styleguide",
    remote = "https://github.com/google/styleguide",
    commit = "26470f9ccb354ff2f6d098f831271a1833701b28",
    build_file = "@//:google_styleguide.BUILD",
)
```

### clang-tidy

I created a custom shell script that roughly looks like this (you'll need to tune which `checks` you want to enable/disable):

```sh
execution_root=$(bazel info execution_root) || exit

clang-tidy \
  -warnings-as-errors=* \
  -header-filter=src/.* \
  -checks="${checks}" \
  "src/"*.cc \
  -- \
    -I "${execution_root}/external/googletest/googletest/include/" \
    -I "${execution_root}/external/absl/" \
    -I "${execution_root}/external/gsl/include/" \
    -I .
```

Comment: Did you manually add BUILD file in styleguide repo. I am seeing the following: `Error in read: Unable to load package for //:google_styleguide.BUILD: BUILD file not found in any of the following directories. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.`

Comment: It's been a little while since I wrestled with this, so I could be forgetting this, but I don't imagine I made any local changes to the Google Styleguide repo; I was just using it as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add file `//cpplint.BUILD` and set visibility for @dimo414 solution to work.

//cpplint.BUILD

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

py_binary(
    name = "cpplint",
    srcs = ["cpplint.py"],
)
```

//WORKSPACE

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "cpplint_archive",
    build_file = "@//:cpplint.BUILD",
    sha256 = "b2979ff630299293f23c52096e408f2b359e2e26cb5cdf24aed4ce53e4293468",
    strip_prefix = "cpplint-1.2.2",
    url = "https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cpplint/cpplint-1.2.2.tar.gz",
)
```

Last is Python test target.

//solution/BUILD

```
py_test(
    name = "solution_cpplint_test",
    srcs = ["@cpplint_archive//:cpplint"],
    args = ["solution/%s" % f for f in glob([
        "**/*.cc",
        "**/*.h",
    ])],
    data = [":solution_filegroup"],
    main = "cpplint.py",
)
```

To run:

```
$ bazel test solution_cpplint_test
```